# XPS 15 9550 top configuration, is it a good choice according to my requirements?

Tags: laptop

It's been 8 years since I last bought a laptop, so I'm very rusty. I would like a laptop which has:

1. a 15'' monitor
2. it's **reliable** (don't want to buy another one anytime soon!)
3. it's lightweight
4. it's a powerful computing enviroment: I like dabbling with machine learning and statistics (I use the open source language R). I have a powerful workstation at work, thus I don't **have** to do computationally intensive stuff at home too, but I sure would like to try it out now and then.
5. I haven't been playing for at least 10 years, but recently I've taken a liking to playing games on my smartphone (Samsung S6), so I was curious to come back to the gaming world and see how it is now.

I've been offered a Dell XPS 15 9550 laptop with [high-end configuration](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-15-9550-laptop/pd?oc=dncwx1634h&model_id=xps-15-9550-laptop#overrides=dncwx1634h:8~512G): basically it's the 15'' Touch screen model (a touch screen on a laptop? sounds weird to me) with the 512 SSD hard disk (curious to see what difference this kind of HD makes with respect to the SATA I knew). It's nearly new (1 month), and I would pay it 1300 € (I live in a European country). Full warranty, etc. Since Dell site prices it at 2050$, it sounded like a good deal and I got a verbal agreement, but...an acquaintance told me that the graphics card is "crap" (his words) and that there are better options at the same price. He pointed me to [this laptop](http://store.hp.com/ItalyStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=E7E59EA&opt=ABZ&sel=NTB). I apologize for the non-English link, but I couldn't find exactly the same laptop on the English HP site. [This one](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/Laptops/omen-laptop---15t-gaming-uhd-w2n30ua-aba) seems the closest one, but note that it has an HD twice as big (!). Anyway, it's not necessary to focus on these two. I just want to know if the XPS 15 9550 Touch is a good laptop, given my requirements, and if not, which one would be a valid alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know if the XPS 15 9550 Touch is a good laptop, given my requirements, and if not, which one would be a valid alternative.

This should be able to handle most things. The CPU is new enough to not be a bottleneck while compiling code, while the GPU is solid enough to push AAA titles to max/ultra settings in 1080p (some games might have to throttle to 30fps).  Here is a point by point break down.

- This model comes in 15.6 and 17.3 inch models.
- This is name brand laptop, using a brand new CPU and GPU, it will last         as long as it meets your needs. If upgrading is a concern, consider a desktop.
- The 15.6 inch model is 4.85 lbs.
- This laptop has a 6th Generation Intel® Core™ i7 processor, its one of the most powerful consumer grade CPU on the market today.
- The GPU will be able to play most games on Max/Ultra settings on 1080p. If there are any specific games you would like to know about google "NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 965M" and the game you're interested in.

Oh and by the way, the HDD to SSD jump is amazing. I went from an old 5400rpm boot drive to a m.2 ssd drive and it is like night and day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the link I posted says that the GPU of the XPS 15 9550 is a GTX 960M, not 965M. Are they similar? Or were you referring to the HP Omen laptop?

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the HP omen I think. But yes the 960M is very similar to the 965M.   Either way, both laptops are VERY well rounded. You shouldn't have any issues with either of them.

Comment: I went for the Omen in the end: same price, brand new, no touch screen (which I didn't need), marginally better GPU. Soooo satisfied now! As you said, going from HDD to SSD was amazing! And in general I find Windows 10 very nice (am I mad?! : )

Comment: AWESOME!!! Glad you are happy!